# What module(s) should I use with Apache to provide SSL termination and Load-Balancing to non-clustered WebLogic instances?

Tags: apache-2.2

We have WebLogic installed on two separate RHEL 5.6 servers. An Apache web server instance will be installed on each of those servers which will be configured to listen on 80 and 443 and redirect any requests from 80 to 443. SSL will terminate at the Apache web server and traffic between the Apache web server and the WebLogic servers will not need to be encrypted. I want the Apache instance to round robin load-balance to the WebLogic servers with sticky sessions and want the web server to be aware if one of the servers is down (and if so, not to route requests to the down server).

What Apache module(s) should I install to set up this configuration?

Note that I am NOT using WebLogic clusters (otherwise I might use WebLogic's WebLogic-Cluster-Aware Apache plugin which can handle the load balancing requirements)

Answer (score -1):

you can use Apache's mod_proxy and its ProxyPass function or better use proxy balancer module(mod_proxy_balancer which supports stickiness) for redirecting the request on non clustered weblogic

And need to set RequestHeader set WL-Proxy-SSL true along with weblogic plugin enabled setting on each manged server

Check below link:

http://theheat.dk/blog/?p=916